# Generate random structured data with PHP

Tags: php

Im wondering how can I go on creating a random PHP value with similar structure as IPv6

> Example: 2001:0db8:85a3:0042:1000:8a2e:0370:7334:nc21

I could use `mt_rand(0000,9999).":"....... and so on` But this creates only numerical values, and its redundant. Is there a simpler way of doing it altha-numerically in say a function?

Thanks every one for feedback and information, in the end I choose to go with the following code bit

```
$randomString = sha1(dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)));
$token = implode(':', str_split($randomString, 4));
```

Result:

> 9ec0:4709:926e:4cbf:fa87:2ac3:03da:f547:485b:6464

Comment: Use [`dechex()`](http://php.net/dechex) then, and the actual numeric span for 4 nibble hex values.

Comment: What are you actually using this for? If it's just to generate a unique ID, there is the [`uniqid`](http://ca3.php.net/uniqid) function.

Comment: Its to generate a completely random Token

Comment: You could randomly create either an integer (as you've already shown you know how to do) or create a character like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438760/generate-random-5-characters-string.  Put both of these methods into a function, and then randomly chose which one to call.  Then you will have either a number or a letter, randomly.

Comment: @user1477388 Thanks for info, but this `$randomString = sha1(dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)));
        $token = implode(':', str_split($randomString, 4));` works out just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cryptografic hash-function. They output hex by default:

```
md5(rand()) // eg: ccc4fd993dd07dac621455c7c924d38f
```

Otherwards [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the return value of [`str_split(md5(rand()), 4)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) with colons to create something like this:

```
implode(':', str_split('ccc4fd993dd07dac621455c7c924d38f', 4));
// ccc4:fd99:3dd0:7dac:6214:55c7:c924:d38f
```

Depending on how many blocks you want to have random use `substr` to truncate the hash.

---

*Note* that this method does not create real randomness. If need need really random data have a look at the answer of Baba.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I was going to suggest, except for using [`uniqid()`](http://ca3.php.net/uniqid) instead of `rand()`, since it adds an extra layer of conflict-avoidance.

Comment: Awesome works like a charm here is what i did `$randomString = sha1(dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)));
        $token = implode(':', str_split($randomString, 4));`

Comment: @user2293381 Note that `sha1` has an output size of 160bit (= 40 hexadecimal characters). IPv6 only has a size of 128bit (= 32 characters). `md5` may be besser suited!

Comment: @TimWolla i was mearly looking for IPv6 structure hence ":". I just did not know how to refer to it, so I just refereed to it as IPv6 structure

Comment: @TimWolla i know just waiting. I got 5 min limit since im a new member

Comment: Note that `rand()` returns a maximum of 2,147,483,647 different numbers, while `md5` has a space of 16^32. You will not efficiently fill the MD5 space with this method at all. If 2,147,483,647 different values are enough, fine; but it's not good enough for the purpose of *unique* values such as IPv6 (I know, that was just an example).

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using `rand`  see [str_shuffle and randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079703/str-shuffle-and-randomness/14079997#14079997) try :

```
echo myRand(36);
```

Output

```
023c:631e:f770:ec5b:f06b:917a:b839:4aea:45b7
```

Function Used

```
function myRand($length, $sep = ":", $space = 4) {
    if (function_exists("mcrypt_create_iv")) {
        $r = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    } else if (function_exists("openssl_random_pseudo_bytes")) {
        $r = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    } else if (is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
        $r = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, $length);
    } else {
        $i = 0;
        $r = "";
        while($i ++ < $length) {
            $r .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
        }
    }
    return wordwrap(substr(bin2hex($r), 0, $length), $space, $sep, true);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest `/dev/random` as another fallback? +1 though.

Comment: `MCRYPT_RAND  = /dev/random` while `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` is `/dev/urandom` ... I used  ` /dev/urandom` because  `/dev/random` will block after the entropy pool is exhausted

Comment: Yeah, I know, but in case both mcrypt and openssl aren't available, `is_readable('/dev/urandom') && file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, $length)` is a simple fallback, probably preferable to `mt_rand`.

Comment: @deceze .. i see your point  .. .. thanks would update the code in a moment

Comment: @Baba I referred your answer in case someone need secure random data instead of a simple and fast method.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a random number between 0 and 65 535 (0xffff) and then convert it into hex using [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php).

Note that the end of your string, `nc21`, is not a valid hexnumber, and therefore not a valid IPv6 address.

Comment: I know, I just used it as reference. Sorry about that