# Random Testimonial in Between each Blog Post on home.php - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, random, advanced-custom-fields

I have the normal WP loop for showing blog posts on home.php. Im trying to get a random div to populate after each blog post. So it will be:

BLOG POST -> RANDOM DIV -> BLOG POST -> RANDOM DIV

and so on...I've tried to create "testimonials" post type and randomize them with WP_Query, but it still will only pull one PER PAGE. I need multiple to display, but differently below each post. I am also using ACF, so I created testimonial custom field blocks, but I still cant them to randomize display multiple items.

PHP (within loop):

```
<a class="row blogRoll"href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <div class="blogImg col-sm-3">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>

   <div class="col-md-9 blogBlack">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</a>
<div class="testimonial">
<?php the_field('testimonial_content1', 'option');
the_field('testimonial_author1','option'); ?>
</div>
<div class="testimonial">
<?php the_field('testimonial_content2', 'option');
the_field('testimonial_author2', 'option'); ?>
</div>
<div class="testimonial">
<?php the_field('testimonial_content3', 'option');
the_field('testimonial_author3', 'option'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var elems = $(".testimonial");
if (elems.length) {
var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  if (i !== keep) {
    $(elems[i]).hide();
  }
 }
}
```

Obviously, the loop is causing me the headache, because it will pull most recent posts and I just need to pull and not DUPLICATE the testimonial divs below a blog post. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of shuffling and outputing the result straight away, you could shuffled an array (pool of testimonials) and then apply the first value to a first `.testimonial` class for example, and a second value from the shuffled array to the second `.testimonial` class, ... etc.

That article might be of some help, [Randomly iterate through array without pulling duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200180/randomly-iterate-through-array-without-pulling-duplicate-values). You could replace numbers by testimonials... Regards.